# Redirect to a URL with a value at end of the javascript automatically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am new to javascript and I want a code for wordpress. I have three select options. City, Area and House/flat. Earlier I used same name for two select options and the result was mydomain/s=mycity&s=house but I want it to be like mydomain/?s=firstoptionvalue+secondoptionvalue+thirdoptionvalue

```
<form method="get" id="searchform">
<select id="text-one">
<option selected value="base">Select City</option>
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
</select>

<select name="a" id="text-two">
<option>Select Your City First</option>
</select>
```

For second I have used script

```
$(function() {      
$("#text-one").change(function() {
$("#text-two").load("mydomain/textdata/" + 
$(this).val() + ".txt");

<h2>Property Type: </h2> <select name="c" id="text-three">
<option value="house">House</option>
<option value="flat">Flats</option>
<option value="plot">Plots</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn2" />
</form>

<span id="s"></span>
```

Id is coming correctly in span. So I want something like when this javascript ends it automatically redirects to the mydomain/s=(thevalue of s concatinated in javascript)

```
<script>
$(function() {      
$("#text-three").change(function() {
document.getElementById('z').innerText = 
document.getElementById('text-one').value + '+' + 
document.getElementById('text-two').value + '+'   
document.getElementById('text-three').value;
}); 
}); 

function myFunction() {
window.open("mydomain/s=z");
}
</script>
```

I need this url mydomain/?s=firstoptionvalue+secondoptionvalue+thirdoptionva‌​lue . At the end i tried to use mydomains/s=s but it's not working. I know nothing about javascript but the value is coming correctly in span id="s" but i don't want it in span. I want it in window.open("mydomain/s=z");

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: just call your function at the end of your script block  like `myFunction();' right before the end of your `</script>` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

window.open(); accepts a string that represents the URL that you want the browser to be directed to.

In this case, window.open("mydomain/s=s"), will redirect to "mydomain/s=s". I'm assuming that when the script is executed that's the URL that you're getting.

With document.getElementById('s').innerText you are setting the contents of the element with id of "s" to the value of "text-one", "text-two", and "text-three".

What you need to do in order to have the page redirect as you would like is either set the value of "text-one", "text-two", and "text-three" to a variable and then use that variable in the URL or use the values directly.

For example:

```
function myFunction() {
window.open("mydomain/?a=" + document.getElementById('text-one').value +   '&b=' + document.getElementById('text-two').value + '&c=' +   document.getElementById('text-three').value;
}
```

OR:

```
function myFunction() {

var a = document.getElementById('text-one').value;
var b = document.getElementById('text-two').value;
var c = document.getElementById('text-three').value;

window.open("mydomain/?a=" a + '&b=' + b + '&c=' + c);
}
```

Finally, you need to call myFunction() somewhere, most likely in an on click event.

Comment: This is accomplished using JavaScript, but it could also be done using jQuery. happymacarts example would also work, which is an example using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i am understanding your question but i believe this is what you are looking for the snippet below will obviously not load mydomain.com or run the window.open but you can modify those lines for your implementation

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text-one").change(function() {
    $("#text-two").load("mydomain/textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
  })

  $("#text-three").change(function() {
    $('#s').text(
      $('#text-one').val() +
     $('#text-two').val() + 
    $('#text-three').val())
    
    var theLink = $('#s').text();
    console.log(' window.open(mydomain.com/?s='+theLink+')');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="searchform">
  <select id="text-one">
    <option selected value="base">Select City</option>
    <option value="city1">city1</option>
    <option value="city2">city2</option>
  </select>

  <select name="a" id="text-two">
    <option>Select Your City First</option>
  </select>

  <h2>Property Type: </h2> 
  <select name="c" id="text-three">
    <option value="house">House</option>
    <option value="flat">Flats</option>
    <option value="plot">Plots</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn2" />
</form>

<span id="s"></span>
```

Comment: Of course i would not usually load the contents into a span but rather just set it to a variable but I was not sure if you needed it to display as well